If we want to apply the formula for torque $= pE\sin\theta$. It is given in the problem that theta~0°
Why do we take sin theta to be theta only and not as sin0° ie., 0?


Please do not post part of books, just type out the relevant part and maybe post a photo of just the drawing in the bottom left. Doing this also improves the searchability of the post

Okay, I'll be doing that from now onwards.

Taylor series expansion about zero for $\sin(x)$ is $$ \sin(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k~ x^{1 + 2 k}} {(1 + 2 k)!} $$. Take only first linear term $k=0$ and you will get that in first order approximation $\sin(x) \approx x$, namely when $x \to 0$. As about why not $0$ is substituted into formula,- @NotLudovico has posted a decent answer.

The key factor here is that the angle $\theta$ is not exactly $0$ but it is really small (hence the $\approx$ symbol).
We are not interested in an exact computation of the acceleration, which would be $0$ if you put $\sin(\theta) = 0$, we are interested in deriving a general formula valid for small $\theta$ that, in this case, resemble the acceleration of an harmonic oscillator. This allows for a computation of the remaining steps as the system were a SHM which in turn simplifies the problem.
In fact you can expand $\sin(\theta)$ as $\sin(\theta) = \theta + O(\theta^3)$ if you are comfortable with power series expansion.
